# "Unexpected token L in JSON at position 0" when using a method from google trends api

Tags: javascript, google-trends

I am trying to make use of the google trends api for a project and today it started acting up. I'm using netbeans as IDE and not even this piece of code works:

```
const googleTrends = require('google-trends-api');
googleTrends.relatedTopics({keyword: 'Chipotle', startTime: new Date('2015-01-01'), endTime: new Date('2017-02-10')})
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I've done a little bit of research about this error and from I understand (I should probably state that I'm new to JS) it has something to do with parsing objects into strings, but I just don't understand how this is the case with my code. 
Moreover, I can't possibly imagine why it worked before but now it doesn't any more.

Comment: did you parsing the res?

Comment: I have tried using JSON.stringify(), but had no success

Comment: I tried the code and it worked fine for me. Try `npm update` (the current version of `google-trends-api` is 4.3.0)

Comment: its getting the error in the api call?

Comment: Could it be that I have reached the limit of queries?

Comment: @zabusa Yes, I think so

Comment: @nedsteven Yes, that's very possible. Did you check http://console.developers.google.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out what the problem was. Apparently, Google's trends API is no longer open source.